# QtCreator 4.3.1 app build crashes when compiled for MSVC 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, qt5

In QtCreator Qt 4.3.1, I create a app what I compiled with mingw, it works, but I've added a lib what needs msvc 2015, I implement the lib in the codes, but the app crashes when starts, I tried to remove all of the use of the lib from the code and that crashes too, I can't use the debugger when I try that generates a error what says the app is closed, it opens and after it closes instantly.

Thank you.

EDIT 1:

Qt Creator Version: 4.3.1
Qt Version: 5.9.1

I've selected the MSVC 2015 64bit kit, in it puts the wrong version, Microsoft Visual C++ 15.0, I change to the 14.0 now I have a path issue, I localized the "cl.exe" in the folder of the microsoft visual studio and adds to the path, restart the IDE and try to compile again, it generates a error:

`C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:45: error: C1083: cannot open included file: 'type_traits': No such file or directory`

Obs.: I'm trying to just compile the app, without the lib.

EDIT 2:

I added the `CONFIG += c++11` to the .pro file, runned qmake and rebuild again, it generates the same error: `C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:45: error: C1083: cannot open included file: 'type_traits': No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you compile Qt 4.3.1 with MSVC 2015? There was never an official package for any Qt4 version beyond MSVC 2010.

Comment: That may be difficult / nearly impossible to do if the builtin qmake does not support MSVC2015.

Comment: I build Qt4.8.X on Visual Studio 2013. Although I have not tried this on MSVC2015 or greater. I just checked my sources for 4.8.7-git do not support building for any version of MSVC > 2013.

Comment: It seems like you are talking about the QtCreator version not the Qt framework version. Are you using Qt5? There will be Qt5 binaries for MSVC2015.

Comment: MSVC2015 is version 14.0. The year only matches the VC version for 2010 all other versions do not match.

Comment: ***When I compile with MSVC 2013 it generates 22 errors*** If your 3rd party library is for Visual Studio 2015 you should use 2015. Don't mix and match compiler versions.

Comment: You can edit this question. And add your errors and exactly what you did to get these errors. Without both I doubt anyone could help. Remember its best to copy Visual Studio error messages from the Output Tab.

Comment: type_traits is a c++11 header, maybe you haven't specified you need c++11? Add a line `CONFIG   += c++11` to your .pro file and do a `Run qmake`